# Adding event listener to table object in corona

Tags: lua, sdk, coronasdk, lua-table

```
local function removeTrumps(obj)
    obj:removeSelf()

    trumps=trumps-1
 --[[local thisTrump=myTrump.id
    display.remove(myTrump[thisTrump])
    myTrump[thisTrump]=nil
    table.remove(myTrump,thisTrump)]]--

    if (timeLeft~=false) then 
        if(trumps==0) then
            timer.cancel(gameTimer)
            gameOver("winner")

        elseif(trumps<=40) then

            gameOver("notbad")
        elseif(trumps>=31) then

            gameOver("loser")
        end

    end
end


local function startGame()
myTrump[#myTrump+1]=display.newImageRect("tp.png",25,25)
myTrump[#myTrump].x=Random(50,_W-50)
myTrump[#myTrump].y=(_H+10)
myTrump[#myTrump].id=#myTrump
physics.addBody(myTrump[#myTrump],"dynamic", {density=.1, friction=0, bounce=.9, radius=9})


 --TOUCH FUNCTION FIX IT
   function onTouch(event)

    if(timeLeft~=false) then

        if (playerReady==true) then
            if(event.phase=="ended") then
            removeTrumps(self)


        end
    end
end
end
--if i put onTouch then removetrumps is ? if i leave it as #myTrump it just doenst recognize the touch
myTrump[#myTrump]:addEventListener("touch", onTouch)
trumps=trumps+1

if(trumps==numTrumps) then
    gameTimer=timer.performWithDelay(1000,countDown,totalTime)
else

    playerReady=false
end
end
```

So here is my problem. I don't know how to properly set the `onTouch` event listener to the table object `#myTrump` and I'm trying to make it so when you click the image it disappears but its not working right. The way it is right now it talks about obj (in the `removeTrumps` function)being a nil value. How do I fix this? The objects aren't disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this `removeTrumps(self)` for `removeTrumps(event.target)`. Another thing, you don't need to compare `boolean` with values `true` or `false`:

```
if timeLeft then --if (timeLeft ~= false) then "not false is true"
    if playerReady then --if (playerReady == true) then
        --some code here
    end
end
```